# modules not found node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm

Am trying to run file with , a **node run index.js**. which inside the folder flashloan test but this is an error that I keep getting,...

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/schette/Documents/flashloan test/run'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v19.2.0
```

what could be the problem, any solution? i tried to remove npm and and reinstall, but still.

I deleted npm packges and reinstall it. I also edited json packeg, scripts with **start: node main.js**

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up two different commands.

`node script_file.js` runs a script with Node.js

`npm run script_name` runs a command defined in [the `scripts` block of a package.json file](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#scripts)

Comment: I just tried everything or every solution I found online and on youtube.. so, what is the best solution?